# textarea fills table cell in jsfiddle but not in real application

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is strange but I have a jsfiddle where when the user clicks on the "Add Question" button to append a table row, under the "Question" column in the appended row, the height and the width of the textarea in this table cell is able to fill the table cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/LKB9e/12/

But the problem is that I have exactly the same code in my application but in my application the textarea does not fill in the table cell. My question is that how come it doesn't work in my application?

[application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable4.php)

The only code I have in my application that is not in fiddle is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Prepare Questions and Answers</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="QandATableStyle4.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/basic.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/basic.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-lightness/basic_ie.css"/>
```

Comment: So take out everything that's not in your JS Fiddle and then add things back, one by one, to see when it breaks. Once you identify which file(s) cause the problems look at what's in that/those files, and debug.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have tried what you said but no difference, except for jquery not working when I remove some of those lines. But what I have realised is that it works in the application for safari and chrome but not for ie, firefox or opera. Why is it not filling table cell for these browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsfiddle uses a css reset to remove margins and padding and cellspacing for all elements amongst many other tweaks. This is because different  browsers set different defaults for various css properties.

You don't appear to be using any reset so you are getting default cell padding showing up as well as cell spacing. Google terms `CSS reset` or `CSS normalize` will turn up lots of info

Comment: I have realised is that it works in the application for safari and chrome but not for ie, firefox or opera. Why is it not filling table cell for these browsers?

Comment: Will I need to link to a second css style sheet and include the css reset code in that page?

Comment: I tried included the css reset code in my style sheet but still not making a difference

Comment: did you place reset before all other css? what reset did you use? Demo page has multiple versions of jQueryUI css loading and doesn't appear to have any reset

Comment: I typed in reset css in google, clicked on the first link and I copied virtually the css code into my current css page

Comment: This is the url: meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

on the main page, remove the border on the textarea:

```
.textAreaQuestion { border: none; }
```

Comment: That doesn't make the textarea bigger and wider to fill the table cell

Comment: when I checked the two sites, they were identical, as in, the textfield was already filled. except on your live page, there was a 1 pixel border around the textarea so that's what I thought you were trying to fix. what browsers are you having the problem with? you should specify that.

Comment: I have realised is that it works in the application for safari and chrome but not for ie, firefox or opera. Why is it not filling table cell for these browsers?